# Onesignal doesn't work on android device(API level 23)

Tags: android, xamarin, onesignal

I try to add OneSignal notification in my app. But when i add this

```
<permission android:name="packagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

it doesn't work on android(6.0 - API 23) and less i guess. it works fine android(7.1). But i need lower devices too. How can i fix it?

> error: Build Failed: Xamarin.Android does not support running the previous version.  Please ensure your solution builds before running or debugging it.

Comment: did you add this line too <uses-permission android:name="${manifestApplicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />  @Fatih akbaba

Comment: i already did but there are no problem with that line. I tried every line one by one if i delete permission line app can be built on API 23. @ALTegani